# How to update arrays concurrently?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, concurrency, nsoperationqueue

I'm trying to realize this: 
I have four arrays and a function "calculateResult" that changes them all. The number of elements of these arrays is 2^n, where n is user-defined value. The function is called in a loop (in real project number of iterations can be 2^10, for example). 
Then break arrays into parts (in real project number of parts = number of processors) and "calculateResult" in range of this parts parallel.

Specific case of what i need (arrays count = 2^10 = 1024, number of parts = 4):

```
import Foundation

    func calculateResult(inRange calculationRange: CountableClosedRange<Int>) -> (ArraySlice<Double>, ArraySlice<Double>, ArraySlice<Double>, ArraySlice<Double>) {
        var array1 = Array(repeating: 0.0, count: calculationRange.count)
        var array2 = Array(repeating: 0.0, count: calculationRange.count)
        var array3 = Array(repeating: 0.0, count: calculationRange.count)
        var array4 = Array(repeating: 0.0, count: calculationRange.count)

        var iRes = 0
        for i in calculationRange {
            array1[iRes] = Double(i * 1)
            array2[iRes] = Double(i * 10)
            array3[iRes] = Double(i * 100)
            array4[iRes] = Double(i * 1000)

            iRes += 1
        }

        return (ArraySlice(array1), ArraySlice(array2), ArraySlice(array3), ArraySlice(array4))
    }

    var result1 = Array(repeating: 0.0, count: 1024)
    var result2 = Array(repeating: 0.0, count: 1024)
    var result3 = Array(repeating: 0.0, count: 1024)
    var result4 = Array(repeating: 0.0, count: 1024)

    func calculateResConcurrent() {
        let operationQueue = OperationQueue.init()

        let op1 = BlockOperation.init {
            print("Operation \(0)...")
            (result1[0...255], result2[0...255], result3[0...255], result4[0...255]) = calculateResult(inRange: 0...255)
            print("Operation \(0) DONE")
        }
        let op2 = BlockOperation.init {
            print("Operation \(1)...")
            (result1[256...511], result2[256...511], result3[256...511], result4[256...511]) = calculateResult(inRange: 256...511)
            print("Operation \(1) DONE")
        }
        let op3 = BlockOperation.init {
            print("Operation \(2)...")
            (result1[512...767], result2[512...767], result3[512...767], result4[512...767]) = calculateResult(inRange: 512...767)
            print("Operation \(2) DONE")
        }
        let op4 = BlockOperation.init {
            print("Operation \(3)...")
            (result1[768...1023], result2[768...1023], result3[768...1023], result4[768...1023]) = calculateResult(inRange: 768...1023)
            print("Operation \(3) DONE")
        }

        operationQueue.addOperations([op1, op2, op3, op4], waitUntilFinished: true)
    }

    let numberOfIterations = 200
    for i in 0...numberOfIterations {
        print("\nMain iteration \(i) of \(numberOfIterations)")
        calculateResConcurrent()
    }

    print("")
    print(result1.last!, result2.last!, result3.last!, result4.last!) //Correct result is: (1023.0, 10230.0, 102300.0, 1023000.0)
```

I run this and sometimes it crash with error: "Fatal error: UnsafeMutablePointer.deinitialize with negative count" or the wrong result is returned.
Help me to find mistake and realize this, please :-) I'm new in swift.

Comment: The code seems to suffer from the "simultaneous access from multiple threads" issue, basically you can end up with multiple operations trying to write to the same array at approx the same time

Comment: @Cristik is right you are `for i in 0...numberOfIterations` and in each iteration you are creating queue -> Operations -> wait untill finish mean while another iteration  is started

Comment: You also don't wait until all operations finish, you try to print the results straight away, which can result in intermediate results being printed, or another crash since you're accessing the array while other threads are modifying it.

Comment: Instead of having each of the four operations update 1/4 of each array, why not have each operation fully populate one array each?

Comment: Cristik, Prashant Tukadiya, Thanks a lot guys!
@rmaddy in the future (about real project) it's planned to connect clusters, so I'm trying to build on the number of processors (number of arrays always = 4, but their count can be for example 2^20...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can eventually do is to introduce a `DispatchQueue` to write synchronously into the arrays and, through `BlockOperation`, keep on running concurrently the rest of your logic, so your function might be:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "syncQueue")

func calculateResConcurrent() {
    let operationQueue = OperationQueue.init()
    operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 4
    let ops:[BlockOperation] = [0...255, 256...511, 512...767, 768...1023].map { range in
        let op = BlockOperation.init(block: {
            let res = calculateResult(inRange: range) // concurrent
            queue.sync(execute: { // synchronous
                result1.replaceSubrange(range, with: res.0)
                result2.replaceSubrange(range, with: res.1)
                result3.replaceSubrange(range, with: res.2)
                result4.replaceSubrange(range, with: res.3)
            })
            print("Operation \(range) finished")
        })
        return op
    }
    operationQueue.addOperations(ops, waitUntilFinished: true)
}
```